# wrong values insertion in database

Tags: android, database

i have written a programme to insert the values in database. i had taken name, phone, address and email, but only name and phone are inserted in database. in the columns of address and email again name and phone are being inserted.
here's my code.

```
edit_phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        edit_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        edit_add=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
        String name1=edit_name.getText().toString();
        String mobile_no1=edit_phone.getText().toString();
        String email1=edit_name.getText().toString();
        String addr1=edit_phone.getText().toString();
        db.execSQL("insert into register values('"+name1+"','"+mobile_no1+"','"+email1+"','"+addr1+"')");
        edit_phone.setText(" ");
        edit_name.setText(" ");
        edit_email.setText(" ");
        edit_add.setText(" ");
        db.close();
```

Comment: Please, use ContentProvider

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    String email1=edit_name.getText().toString();
    String addr1=edit_phone.getText().toString();
```

To

```
    String email1=edit_email.getText().toString();
    String addr1=edit_add.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's where your problem lies:

```
String email1=edit_name.getText().toString();
String addr1=edit_phone.getText().toString();
```

You're storing the name in the email variable, and the phone in the address variable.